# Emacs calc multiple solutions

Tags: emacs, calc

I have this minimal code:

```
(progn
  (calc)
  (calc-hyperbolic)
  (calc-eval "[8.66e10 = r * v, -7.51e6 = 0.5*v^2 - 6.67e-11*6e24/r]" 'push)
  (calc-solve-for "[r,v]")
  (print (calc-eval 1 'top))
  (calc-quit))
```

And I get the generic solution

```
"[r = 86600000000. / (4621.24711316 - 2517.12631405 s2), v = 4621.24711316 - 2517.12631405 s2]"
```

In the manual I read:

> "The Hyperbolic flag (H a S) [fsolve] tells the solver to report the
>   fully general family of solutions. It will invent variables n1, n2, …,
>   which represent independent arbitrary integers, and s1, s2, …, which
>   represent independent arbitrary signs (either +1 or -1)." ... "Note
>   that variables like n1 and s1 are not given any special interpretation
>   in Calc except by the equation solver itself. As usual, you can use
>   the s l (calc-let) command to obtain solutions for various actual
>   values of these variables."

How can I proceed programmatically to get the two solutions, aka, substitute s2 (I do not know why s2 instead of s1 ???) by +1 and -1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(progn
  (calc)
  (calc-hyperbolic)
  (calc-eval "[8.66e10 = r * v, -7.51e6 = 0.5*v^2 - 6.67e-11*6e24/r]" 'push)
  (calc-solve-for "[r,v]")
  (calc-eval -1 'push) ; value for variable s2
  (calc-let 'var-s2)   ; right name of variable s2
  (print (calc-eval 1 'top))
  (calc-quit))
```

Thank you.